# Multiple joins alternatives

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a `Parent` and `Child` table like this:

```
Parent
    id bigint (PK)

Child
    id bigint (PK)
    parentId bigint (FK)
    name varchar
    stringValue varchar
    longValue bigint
    dateValue timestamp
```

Suppose the data in the tables is like this:

```
Parent:
    id
    1

Child:
    id    idParent    name    stringValue    longValue    dateValue
     1        1        v1         myStr         NULL         NULL  
     2        1        v2         NULL           1           NULL
     3        1        v3         NULL          NULL         2021-05-04 00:00:00
```

I would like to get in a row all the variable that have the `idParent = 1` and the respected set value.. The way it's done right now is this:

```
SELECT  v1.STRINGVALUE_ as v1, v2.LONGVALUE_ as v2, v3.DATEVALUE_ as v3 
FROM Parent p
    LEFT JOIN Child v1 ON (v1.idParent = p.id AND v1.name =  'v1')  
    LEFT JOIN Child v2 ON (v2.idParent = p.id AND v2.name =  'v2')  
    LEFT JOIN Child v3 ON (v3.idParent = p.id AND v3.name =  'v3')
```

Result of this query is:

```
v1        v2        v3
myStr     1         2021-05-04 00:00:00
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve this task.

---

Update: Suppose also that the `not null` value for each row is not known in advance, meaning that `v1, v2, v3` in the `Child` table above could have different values

Are there better alternatives or any at all?

Using PostgreSQL

Comment: If you need 3 distinct columns, then this is a good way to do it.

Comment: I'm pretty bad at making queries honestly.. The first thing that comes to my mind in such a query is that doing multiple joins like this is creating a lot of catersian products and that doesn't scale very well maybe?

Comment: You are doing joins, not cartesian products

Comment: You could `GROUP BY p.id` and use `max(v1.STRINGVALUE_)`, `max(v2.LONGVALUE_)` etc.

Comment: Isn't a join a cartesian product at first and then only a subset of this product is returned based on the `on` or `where` condition?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe based on the answer of Ftisiot this won't work, the `not null` value for each column is not known in advance

Comment: I meant to join the table multiple times, like in the query in your question. The `GROUP BY` and `max` is just to flatten it into a single row. Perhaps I misunderstood what you want...

Comment: Maybe i don't understand what you're trying to say.. The query on my question already has a single row in the output (?)

Answer (score 1):

If your table structure and fields are fixed like in the example your query is in general terms optimal. I, on the other case, you have only and always one `not null` value for each of the `stringValue`, `longValue`, `dateValue`. You could do all with one join like

```
SELECT  p.id, 
max(case when v.name = 'v1' then v.STRINGVALUE_ end) as v1, 
max(case when v.name = 'v2' then v.LONGVALUE_ end) as v2, 
max(case when v.name = 'v3' then v.DATEVALUE_ end) as v3 
FROM Parent p
    LEFT JOIN Child v ON (v.idParent = p.id)  
GROUP by p.id
```

Comment: No, suppose that there is always one `not null` value for `stringValue`, `longValue` or `dateValue` for each row in the `Child` table but it is not known in advance, so i guess the query you proposed with a single join would not work in this case..